# Azure App Service 500 error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'containerId')

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have an app service which has been running ok, I added blob storage & got that working locally.

When I published the app it is no longer running.
It's been difficult to track down logs but I found this in 'Availability & Performance' in Azure Portal.

I thought maybe there was something wrong with the config but the appsettings file seems to have published ok.
Been stuck with this issue for a while as I'm quite new to Azure

> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'containerId')
> at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient.GetContainer(String databaseId, String containerId)
> at **xxx**.Services.MemberService..ctor(CosmosClient dbClient, String databaseName, String containerName) in C:**xxx**\source\repos**xxx**\Services\MemberService.cs:line 16
> at **xxx**.Startup.InitializeCosmosMemberClientInstanceAsync(IConfigurationSection configurationSection) in C:**xxx**\source\repos**xxx**\Startup.cs:line 99
> at **xxx**.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:**xxx**\source\repos**xxx**\Startup.cs:line 54
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0(IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services, Object instance)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
> at **xxx**.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:**xxx**\source\repos**xxx**\Program.cs:line 16

The Service is initialized in startup like so

```
        private static async Task<FilesService> InitializeCosmosFilesClientInstanceAsync(IConfigurationSection configurationSection)
    {
        string databaseName = configurationSection.GetSection("DatabaseName").Value;
        string memberFilesContainer = configurationSection.GetSection("MemberFilesContainer").Value;

        string account = configurationSection.GetSection("Account").Value;
        string key = configurationSection.GetSection("Key").Value;

        Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient client = new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient(account, key);
        FilesService filesService = new FilesService(client, databaseName, memberFilesContainer);
        Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.DatabaseResponse database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);
        await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(memberFilesContainer, "/id");

        return filesService;
    }
```

And called in the ConfigureServices method like so

```
                services.AddSingleton<IFilesService>(InitializeCosmosFilesClientInstanceAsync(Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDbProd")).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```

The appsetting.json file has the following set

```
"CosmosDbProd": {
"Account": "xxx",
"Key": "xxx",
"DatabaseName": "xxx-db-prod",
"ContainerName": "Member",
"MemberFilesContainer": "MemberFiles"
```

},

Comment: It says:  `Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'containerId') at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient.GetContainer(String databaseId, String containerId)`. I assume that the `containerId` is `null`. Where did you configure it?

Comment: Hi Roman, I've updated the question to show this, thanks

Comment: Please do not show your code as a picture. Edit your question to replace it by code cut and pasted from the IDE. Once you have, select it and press Ctrl-K to format it as a code block. Where do you configure MemberFilesContainer in your App Service?

Comment: Updated @RomanMarusyk thank you for continuing to look

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug!
In appsettings.json I had a section named 'ContainerName' which should have been 'MemberContainer'. I think writing out in here helped me get to the answer